# Sorting specific positions of a vector of pair

Tags: c++, sorting, c++17, stdvector, std-pair

Each element of the vector is a pair of integers, where the first integer represents the value and the second integer represents if the element is locked or unlocked (0  means that the element at that position is unlocked and 1 means that the element at that position is locked).

We can take the values on the unlocked positions, rearrange them in any order and place them back into the unlocked positions. We are not allowed to remove any values, add the new ones, or rearrange the values on the locked positions. We are allowed to leave the values in the same order as they were.

I want to sort the unlocked positions in decreasing order. It can be done in other ways but I tried below code logic.

```
sort(array.begin(),array.end(),[](auto a,auto b){ if(a.second==0 && b.second==0)return a.first>b.first; });
```

For an input like,
{ {-8,1},{4,0},{-2,0},{-6,0},{4,1},{7,1},{1,0} }

I get the output,
{ {4,0},{1,0},{-2,0},{-6,0},{-8,1},{4,1},{7,1} }

Here I tried implementing sorting to only unlocked positions but found out that locked positions also changed their positions.

My expected output is,
{ {-8,1},{4,0},{1,0},{-2,0},{4,1},{7,1},{-6,0} }

My question is, why I am getting that output? And how to modify the sort function to get my expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to sort a subset which doesn't form a continuous range, then you must extract that subset first.

Easiest way to do so, is to copy only the set of unlocked options to a new container, sort it, and then iterate over both the original container and your sorted container with a pair of iterators to find the "unlocked" spots where the sorted elements can now be written to.

Comment: I understand your solution. But is it the only way to solve this? I was looking for an alternate solution that uses lambda function inside sort function.

Comment: Nothing building on `std::sort`, as the predicate would be queried for pairs which must not be sorted, giving inevitably wrong input to the sort function. You don't have "I don't know, please ignore" as a legal return value for the comparator.

Comment: With C++20 you could use a filter view on your original vector and then run `std::sort` on the view rather than the backing container, but you can't use a C++20 solution yet, can you? At least would avoid the temporary copy, but also with a lot of overhead.

Comment: @Ext3h You can't `sort` a `view`, you can only sort a l-value container.